# Why open-wc scaffold does not add required tools as a direct dependency

Tags: web-component, native-web-component

I have a webcomponent project that I had setup from a very simple setup but I'd like to use open-wc. After scaffolding a project for webcomponent, I noticed my dependencies look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lit-html": "^1.1.2",
    "lit-element": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "es-dev-server": "^1.23.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "@open-wc/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@open-wc/prettier-config": "^0.1.10",
    "husky": "^1.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.0.0",
    "@open-wc/testing-karma": "^3.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^3.2.0",
    "@open-wc/testing-karma-bs": "^1.0.0",
    "@open-wc/testing": "^2.0.0",
    "@open-wc/demoing-storybook": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Instead of having a direct dependencies on various tools, it seems there's an additional layer of dependencies (i.e. `@open-wc/eslint-config`, `@open-wc/prettier-config`, `@open-wc/demoing-storybook`).

Why is that extra layer needed? Why wouldn't I want to have direct dependencies on those tools? For some there is a direct dependency (i.e. `eslint`), but for others they are coming through that additional layer (i.e. storybook, prettier, etc).

I'm having a little difficulty understanding the overall setup.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask open-wc for their specific reason but one reason is so they can build and test for a single dependency version. If they rely on peerDependencies there could be no telling what version would be installed.